# Finish activity on google maps marker tap

Tags: android-intent

Hi i am starting an intent when i tap a marker on Google maps using a class that detects the taps...

I can start an intent when i tap a marker...

```
 Intent test = new Intent(mContext, testing.class);
                  mContext.startActivity(test);
```

But i want to close the current intent with i start the new one... how can i do this on tap ??

The problem is that the intent i don't close keeps running behind the new one every time and i get memory force close...

Comment: Create a public static variable to hold the context of the main activity you run google maps on and then use the following code....

Lets say the activity that holds Google maps is named test.

    Public static Context contextoftest;
    
    On the resume of test...
    
    contextoftest = this;

On the Ontap method of overlays class call....

    ((test) test.contextoftest).finish();

Answer (score 0):

Create a public static variable to hold the context of the main activity you run google maps on and then use the following code....

Lets say the activity that holds Google maps is named test.

```
Public static Context contextoftest;

On the resume of test...

contextoftest = this;
```

On the Ontap method of overlays class call....

```
((test) test.contextoftest).finish();
```